# Inside Docker: mkdir(-p): No such file or directory

Tags: bash, docker, mkdir

I have encountered a strange problem where the mkdir -p command fails to create a directory and returns the following error message:

```bash
[root@202 ~]# pwd
/root
[root@202 ~]# mkdir -p a/b/c
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘a’: No such file or directory
```

However, if I execute the same command in the root directory, it works fine:

```bash
[root@202 /]# pwd
/
[root@202 /]# mkdir -p a/b/c
[root@202 /]# ls -lhrt a/b
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 6 Mar 13 15:06 c
```

I am currently logged in as the root user, so I don't think it's a simple permission issue.

Do you have any other ideas for troubleshooting?

The permissions of the /root directory are as follows:

```bash
[root@202 ~]# ls -lhart /
dr-xr-x---    2 root root  114 Apr  1  2016 root
```

And when I tried to modify the permissions of the /root directory, I encountered the same strange phenomenon:

```bash
[root@202 ~]# chmod a+w ~
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/root’: No such file or directory
```

I am currently working within a Docker container and the system is CentOS 7.

Docker version: 6e3bb8e/1.13.1 (released on 2017-02-08).

Thanks in advance.

---

The `df` of `/` and `/root`:

```bash
[root@202 /]# df -lh /root
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay         128G   14G  115G  11% /
```

If I try to create the /root directory (given the "No such file or directory" message earlier):

```bash
[root@202 /]# mkdir /root
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root’: File exists
```

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, I've seen it later, so I deleted my comment.

Comment: hmmm ... `overlay` filesystem ... can you `touch ~/foo`?

Comment: Is it possible to provide us with a minimal reproducing example, e.g., a `Dockerfile` or publicly accessible Docker image that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: @Green绿色 It's not a public image, but I can show you the docker inspected information (I'm not familiar with docker, please tell me which one is required). The Dockerfile only installs some dependencies packages and runs a service process.

Comment: I think Docker used to have a bug (in year 2017 or so) that caused symptoms like these, especially if your container was very complex (hitting the maximum number of overlays, as it was at the time). But that must have been fixed years ago... is your Docker version up to date? Or is the container perhaps an old one, possibly created with a buggy version?

Comment: @telcoM Wow, the Docker version we're using is exactly 6e3bb8e/1.13.1 (released on 2017-02-08). Could you have any more detail about this bug?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a hazy memory (otherwise I would have written an answer). But please **edit that Docker version information into the main question**: these comments will eventually expire, and without the version information the question might be harder to find and/or less useful for others, and the fact that you are using an old version of Docker may be critical in this case.

Comment: While exploring this issue, you could start with a public CentOS7 image and successively add your layers once at a time until the problem occurs. Alternatively, you could do binary search on the intermediate images. Every layer creates a new image and you could just run `docker run -it --entrypoint bash IMAGE_SHA` to explore this image. The image SHA is printed to stdout and is usually found in a line like this: `---> ff5722d1c4b4`.

Comment: @ilkkachu In fact, the initial issue was the inability to install any packages via rpm, and the strace was not previously installed inside the container.

And the issue was finally resolved by reboot...

Comment: okay, so probably not too easy to find out what was wrong before the reboot...